# Shortcode Attributes not being passed to handler function

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, shortcode

Not sure what but the attributes from the shortcode aren't being passed to the handler function.

Shortcode in Wordpress Post

```
[k_recipe recipe="snack"]Here is some content[/k_recipe]
```

Shortcode Function

```
add_shortcode("k_recipe", "recipe_shortcode");

function recipe_shortcode($attributes, $content){

    return "Hi " . $attributes["recipe"] . " Hi " . $content;
}
```

Shortcode Output

```
Hi  Hi Here is some content
```

Why isnt the snack value being passed?? Any clue??

Comment: So I restarted my computer and it seems to be working now. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how to use shortcode with attributes

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'bartag_func' );

[myshortcode foo="bar" bar="bing"]
```

you are missing extract thing

Comment: Isnt the extract method just to pull the values out and into their own values??

Comment: My issue is that is doesnt even seem like the attribute is being passed at all.

Comment: Okay so I did use both shortcode_atts and extract. shortcode_atts is overriding my values even when its suppose to be getting passed. From my understanding shortcode_atts is suppose to provide defaults in case a value isnt passed. The thing is I AM passing a value but it is coming into the function as null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use the extract function like documentation says:

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: $atts is coming in as null though. All this does it override the value of null with defaults. But I am passing something to $atts. I don't understand why it is null.